# Add constraints to the elemets of List

Tags: grails, command, constraints

Is there are any possible way to add constraints to the elements of List? For example I have a command which accept List and I want add constraints on this elements, for example on size.

```
class SongCommand {

    String title
    List<String> couplet
    List<String> chorus
    Boolean isChorus
    Boolean isChorusRepeat

    static constraints = {
        title(blank: false, maxSize: 6)
        isChorus(blank: true)
    }

}
```

How to do that?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The constraint `size` will work for this purpose. Check the [documentation](http://grails.github.io/grails-doc/latest/ref/Constraints/size.html) for complete details, but your example would be:

```
static constraints = {
  ...
  chours(size:0..3) // example of minimum of 0 maximum of 3
  ...
}
```

The above will limit the number of elements (min and max), however if you want to validate the contents of the list, e.g. each element you will need to implement a custom [validator](http://grails.github.io/grails-doc/latest/ref/Constraints/validator.html) to do so. For example:

```
static constraints = {
  chours(validator: { val ->
    boolean isValid = true 
    val.each {
      if (it.size() < 3) isValid = false
    } 

    return isValid
  })
}
```

The above example validates that each element in the list is three characters or more in size.

Comment: No, I add constraints couplet(maxSize: 6) and validator didn't catch this, but title work.

Comment: Correct, `maxSize` won't work on a list. Read my answer carefully. If you want to limit the number of elements you must use the `size` constraint with a range. if you want to check the maximum length or size of each element you have to use a custom validator routine.